# AWS SNS to Lambda, how many message per invoke?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an SNS topic to which a lambda is subscribed.
In the subscribed lambda, in the event parameter, I have a Records attribute which turns out to be an array and containing (at least) one message from SNS.
That's why I'm wondering if, at some point, it is possible that my lambda is invoked with more than one SNS message. 

In the AWS Documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-package.html), they only look at Records[0] however. I could not find any information on why is that Records in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [FAQs for Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#reliability)...

> **Q: Will a notification contain more than one message?**
>
> No, all notification messages will contain a single published message.

Comment: Youps, I have been searching for that information on every doc page but the FAQ... --